# Read data from HID device in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth, hid

How to read data from HID device onto my iOS app in Objective C? I am trying to scan a barcode using external scanner and retrieve the data.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work in iOS, but I've created a class to simplify that in macOS. Check if it works for you: https://github.com/vitor251093/ObjectiveC_Extension/blob/master/ObjectiveC_Extension/IODeviceObserver.m 
https://github.com/vitor251093/ObjectiveC_Extension/blob/master/ObjectiveC_Extension/IODeviceObserver.h

Comment: Still, there is something you need to know: IOKit (the framework used to access HID devices) is a private framework, so if you use it in a project, you won't be able to add it to the App Store, since Apple will reject it.

Comment: Okay Thank you @vitormm

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this out?

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/EADemo/Introduction/Intro.html

Also, having worked on this problem previously, I found non-MFI HID devices (like all the cheap BT scanners on eBay) function only as an external keyboard on iOS, unless you go the guidelines-breaking route @vitormm presented. To use an external keyboard for scanning in a guideline-compliant way, you need a UITextField or UITextView to be firstResponder when the user hits the scan button to capture the scan, or the scan will go into the bit bucket. From there, you'll need to use the textDelegate protocol and a timer to discern the end of the scan, or program the scanner to send a terminator character like a Carriage Return in between scans, and scan the input stream for the terminator.

Additionally, in my survey from about a year ago, I found most manufacturers of MFI barcode scanners provide a library to interface to their scanners. These function on a delegate callback or NSNotification type of architecture, which is what you really need for any sort of sophisticated mobile scanning application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Finally worked with time delay.